# sudo password automation is not working as expected when executing from crontab?

Tags: linux, bash, cron

I have a shell script as follows.

abc.sh

```
echo "Password" | sudo -S /etc/init.d/mysqld status
```

It is working fine when I am executing directly from shell. My problem comes into picture when I am trying to execute the same as **cron (crontab)**, it is not working. sudo -S options is not working well with crontab. Is there any other option to specify sudo password in shell script(automation)

I could try modifing the /etc/sudoers file by adding NOPASSWD option, if I have root access. But unfortunately I dont have root access to modify /etc/sudoers file. I have the sudo access only for executing certain commands.

Comment: Does user cron have `sudo` permission?

Comment: yes, but only for executing some commands like /etc/init.d/mysqld ..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sudo -S seems to works on my Ubuntu 12.04:

```
# m h  dom mon dow   command
 * * * * * cat /etc/shadow > /tmp/shadow.txt 2>&1
```

results in:

```
$ cat /tmp/shadow.txt 
cat: /etc/shadow: Permission denied
```

whereas

```
# m h  dom mon dow   command
* * * * * echo 'password' | sudo -S cat /etc/shadow > /tmp/shadow.txt 2>&1
```

results in:

```
$ head /tmp/shadow.txt 
[sudo] password for user: root:!:15736:0:99999:7:::
daemon:*:15453:0:99999:7:::
bin:*:15453:0:99999:7:::
...
```

**Edit**:

Here's a hack to get the above Ubuntu code to work on CentOS 6.4:

```
* * * * * export DISPLAY=:0 && gnome-terminal -e 'bash -c "echo password | sudo -S cat /etc/shadow > /tmp/shadow 2>&1"'
```

Comment: I am using Cent OS 6.5. It might be a bug in cent OS

Comment: Oh, I see. I tried my example on a CentOS 6.4 VM and it didn't work.  Did you get the following error:  "sudo: sorry, you must have a tty to run"?  If so, are you able to do a sudo crontab -e? (root crontab).

Comment: cool hack, great work. 
my machine is a webserver with base cent OS linux, doesn't have "gnome",kde (No desktop environments)